# Splitting the input into vectors

Tags: java, vector, io

I must split this input from file into vectors and add to a vectors.

File input

```
    1,375,seller
   1,375,sellers
   1,375,send
   1,375,sister
   1,375,south
   1,375,specific
   1,375,spoiler
   1,375,stamp
   1,375,state
   1,375,stop
   1,375,talked
   1,375,tenant
   1,375,today
   1,375,told

    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("e://inputfile.txt");
        // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)  
        {
            Vector dataPoints = new Vector();
            dataPoints.add(br);


             dataPoints.add(new DataPoint());
        }


   ------ public DataPoint(double x, double y, String name) this is the method
```

How to split the string into double and string and give a input to the vector?

Comment: Read up on [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and [`Double.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Why would you use a `Vector` instead of an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [String#split(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Vector<DataPoint> dataPoints = new Vector<DataPoint>();        
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] array = strLine.split(",");
    dataPoints.add(new DataPoint(Double.parseDouble(array[0]), Double.parseDouble(array[1]), array[2]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just split the String returned from the `Bufferedreader` using `String.split()` using `,` as a **delimiter**. and also consider using an `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`, unless you care about **thread safety** and also make your collections generic.

```
 Vector<DataPoint> dataPoints = new Vector<DataPoint>();   
 while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)  
        {
            String[] arr = strLine.split(",");
            DataPoint point = new DataPoint(Double.valueOf(arr[0]), Double.valueOf(arr[1]), arr[2]);
            dataPoints.add(point);
        }
```

Comment: Goof advice to not use the raw type, bad advice to use Vector. Javadoc says: _If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`._

Comment: Your code won't compile in this case because his method accepting two double parameters. And you are passing String value as arr[0] and arr[1].

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis good catch, thanks, i have updated it now :)

Comment: And also what is the point of having a Vector inside a loop :)

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis true, i have just copied OP's code and made some changes :P, thanks again :)